# What are the limitations of Gaussian copulas in respect to pricing credit derivatives?

Tags: credit, valuation

The practice of using Gaussian copulas in modeling credit derivatives has come under a lot of criticism in the past few years. What are the major arguments against using the copula method in this respect?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The limitations of the Gaussian copula were well-known among the quantitative finance practitioners before the crisis. See [this paper by D. Brigo](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5427).

To answer the question:

- no "fat tails"
- unable to fit the market prices without tweaks (base correlation) which make the model arbitrageable
- it's a static model (e.g. forward-starting tranches are impossible to price -- but nobody trades them now anyway)

This said, all other models are either worse or offer cosmetic improvements. Changing the Gaussian factors to some others doesn't really give you much. A few years ago the Random Factor Loading model was en vogue, but it turned out to be much harder to calibrate, and still not flexible enough.

Comment: to add to this its also a martingale process

Answer (score 9):

If you want a 'pop science' account for it, the [Wired article by Felix Salmon](http://www.wired.com/techbiz/it/magazine/17-03/wp_quant?currentPage=all) is a pretty good start.

If you want harder technical stuff, well then you can start at [the Wikipedia article and its section on Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28statistics%29#Applications) and follow the references:

> [...] Some believe the
>   methodology of applying the Gaussian
>   copula to credit derivatives to be one
>   of the reasons behind the global
>   financial crisis of 2008–2009.[6][7]
>   Despite this perception, there are
>   documented attempts of the financial
>   industry, occurring before the crisis,
>   to address the limitations of the
>   Gaussian copula and of Copula
>   functions more generally, specifically
>   the lack of dependence dynamics and
>   the poor representation of extreme
>   events[8]. The volume "Credit
>   Correlation: Life After Copulas",
>   published in 2007 by World Scientific,
>   summarizes a 2006 conference held by
>   Merrill Lynch in London where several
>   practitioners attempted to propose
>   models rectifying some of the copula
>   limitations. See also the article by
>   Donnelly and Embrechts [9] and the
>   book by Brigo, Pallavicini and
>   Torresetti [10].

Comment: was not looking for the pop-sci version but it was an interesting read :)

Comment: The Wired article is basically false. The crisis was only superficially related to problems with copula models. The main reasons were:
- systematic mispricing of mortgage-related derivatives in the US market, due to reliance on false information (NINJA borrowers lying about their income), ultra-optimistic assumptions (one rating agency assumed that house prices will be increasing forever) and ignoring of counterparty risk
- the so-called "monoline debacle", where banks lost billions of dollars by massively underestimating the counterparty risk of insurance they bought on super-senior tranches.

Comment: Yes, Felix Salmon is living proof of the old adage that "a little knowledge is a dangerous thing".